# Why doesn't jQuery form validation plugin work in my page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Why does not jQuery form validation plug-in work?
This is the code:

```
<form id="form2" action="comment.php?id=5" method="post">
    <div>Input your own comment:</div>
<textarea id="textarea2" name="textarea2" rows="3" cols="29"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#form2").validate(
    { 
        rules: { 
         textarea2: {
            required: true,
             minlength:30

        }
        }, 
          messages: { 


        }); 
 }); 
</script>
```

And

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

exists in the header of this page.

The jQuery plugin doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Tip: If you not already did, install firebug (http://getfirebug.com/), which is a great debugging environment for web development.

Comment: Can you tell if you are getting any error messages when you run the code? Maybe try using firebug in firefox to see if the script is actually running or not.

Comment: Hello Steven,

I am only counting 5 open and only 4 closing wiggly brackets.

there is a } missing from your message: element

have you missed a } from your code when transferring the code to this site?

Comment: @Luke Duddridge, you are right. I missed a closing wiggly bracket.I have fixed with the help of your suggestion. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried to do just:

```
$("#form2").validate();
```

on the document ready!
To see if that is working?

Also, try this to see what value you get:

```
alert($("#form2").validate().form());
```

it return bool.

And of course you need to add :

```
class="required"
```

to your text area.
And try to give a name and a id to your elements, that are different if at all possible!

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by [the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812866/why-doesnt-jquery-form-validation-plugin-work-in-my-page#comment1702105_1812866), there is a missing brace as indicated below...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#form2").validate({ 
        rules: { 
            textarea2: {
                required: true,
                minlength:30
            }
        }, 
        messages: { 

        } // <- this brace was missing
    }); 
});
```